# howto: use SSRS in integrated mode on my ASP.net site

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services

OK, so I have a sharepoint site that is using SSRS (in integrated mode, of course) however, I need to have a ASP.net site where I can view these reports.

I can browse to and view the report in my document library on the sharepoint site, but when i set up the ReportViewer on my ASP.Net page, I keep getting a COM error that says "The file you are attempting to save or retrieve has been blocked from this Web site by the server administrators"

could this just be a security issue, where I need to impersonate?

Anyone know how I can do this, or if this is even possible?

SqlServer/SSRS 2005
Sharepoint 2007
ASP.Net using .net 4

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that no one knows or wants to answer.  What we ended up doing is installing a second instance on the same server. Not really what we wanted to do, but meh, it gets the job done.